# Its possible make collision from GL_LINE_LOOP(asteroid) object and a Point Object(bullet)?

Tags: c++, polygon, freeglut

I just have a asteroid object created by vertex2f and GL_LINE_LOOP and bullet create by vertex2f. I need know if possible made collision by lines?
Cause the polygons is created by lines.
thanks

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes

Comment: [Point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) might help

Comment: but my doubt is my asteroid have 10 vertex2f and my bullet is a GL_POINT 1 vertex2f how detect collision by AABB? Bullet is a object oriented but how got positions of lines to check with bullet?

Comment: I need collision true when bullet cross any line of polygon

Comment: if you have an AABB collision detection should be no problem. do you need to know how to calculate the AABB in world-space from your polygon?

Comment: Asteroids are in the class will have many and bullets too.I need create more simple possible method for collisions when cross lines between bullet and asteroid i think but dont know if AABB is better in this case. I would need calculate from 10 lines? cause Asteroid is a big and have many lines and all lines have diferents positions in worldspace.

Comment: Or can use AABB in a Virtual Rectangle mode? but dont will have good precision cause the asteroids rotating on the space everytime.May be the bullet will collide in the empty space before real line of asteroid

Comment: in my class bullet have a bullet bullet_fire[7] have a max 7 bullets on the screen working like bullet_fire[1].posX, bullet_fire[1].posY..... Need help how just create for 1 bullet the code collsion for work for all bullets.My game start with 6 asteroids when collide with bullet will scale/2 and add new asteroid with same scale at the side.